# Convert Data from fox pro table to sql server with c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foxpro

I want write an win-form application to convert data from foxpro table into sql server.when i convert or transfer data in foxpro (with foxpro) my data is transfered very speed.but when i try to convert into sql server ,data is transfered very slow.how can i solve this problem.what technologies can i use? what tips can i use? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx).

In particular, [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c32c0820-0e2d-4461-820a-530541c769c6/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that there is a great tool that will mass transfer data from FoxPro straight into SQL Server. If the tables are not already in a DBC, you'll need to make a copy of the entire data set to a new folder, then add those tables to a DBC, then run this SQL Server Upsizing Wizard. Works with SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

http://vfpx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sedna#SQLServerUpsizing